# Number system convertion with Recursive function - Error in return value

Tags: delphi, recursion, number-systems

I have to make a program where I have to convert numbers from the decimal system into another one (base 2 to 9), like in my first question.

But this time I have to make it using a recursive function. So I came with:

```
function cambiarBase(n,b: integer): string;
Begin
if n < b then
  cambiarBase := inttostr(n)
else 
  cambiarBase := inttostr(n mod b) + cambiarBase(n div b, b);
End;
```

It takes 2 integer variables, 'n' being the decimal number and 'b' being the base, and returns a string with the converted number. At the button procedure I show the number in a TMemo

```
memo1.Lines.Add(cambiarBase(n,b));
```

The problem I have is: with the function the way it is gives the digits in the reverse order
(e.g. 301 in base 9 is 364, but its shown as 463). But if I use a ReverseString function after the if statement then the number its shown in a different order (in the example, the number would be now 634).

But if I apply the ReverseString function at the memo1.Lines.Add (outside of the function) then it shows the correct convertion.

What I want is to know how can I make it return the correct order of the digits by the function itself.

The program compiles it without any errors.

Again, thanks for reading.

LeoAM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to reverse the order of concatenation. Instead of:

```
cambiarBase := inttostr(n mod b) + cambiarBase(n div b, b);
```

you write

```
cambiarBase := cambiarBase(n div b, b) + inttostr(n mod b);
```

If you think about this it should be obvious that the concatenation should be this way round. In that expression, the `inttostr(n mod b)` term is the less significant term and so appears on the right.

For what it is worth, I think that this code reads much better if you use `Result` rather than the function name. Especially for a recursive function it can be hard visually to distinguish between the result variable and the recursive call. I'd write it like this:

```
function cambiarBase(n, b: Integer): string;
begin
  if n < b then
    // termination
    Result := IntToStr(n)
  else 
    // recursive step
    Result := cambiarBase(n div b, b) + IntToStr(n mod b);
end;
```

---

Let's work through a simple example for the sake of illustration. Let's say 27 base 4 which we know to be equal to 123 (16 + 2*4 + 3).

```
cambiarBase(27, 4) = cambiarBase(6, 4) + inttostr(3)
```

Next we need to evaluate

```
cambiarBase(6, 4) = cambiarBase(1, 4) + inttostr(2)
```

And finally the termination

```
cambiarBase(1, 4) = inttostr(1)
```

Plug it all together and you have

```
cambiarBase(27, 4) = inttostr(1) + inttostr(2) + inttostr(3)
```

Comment: Thank you, my fault I didn't thought of inverting the order of the concatenation. When I got the result in the inverted order, I thought I could just use the ReverseString function. Also, in the class we use the function name instead of 'result', but I'll make note of using it when I ask questions here.

Comment: If they teach you function name in class that's fine. And that's how it's done in classic Pascal. The special Result variable is a Delphi extension.